# How to play a local video in Vue-plyr?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, plyr.js, vue-plyr

I can get `vue-plyr` to work with a youtube video like so:

```
<template>
  <section id="vision" class="vision">
    <vue-plyr>
      <div data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="bTqVqk7FSmY"></div>
    </vue-plyr>
  </section>
</template>
```

but when I try to use a local video like described in the [doc](https://github.com/redxtech/vue-plyr):

```
<template>
  <section id="vision" class="vision">
    <vue-plyr :options="options">
      <video
        controls
        crossorigin
        playsinline
      >
        <source
          size="1080"
          src="../../videos/cgi_neutral.mp4"
          type="video/mp4"
        />
      </video>
    </vue-plyr>
  </section>
</template>
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
    at Object../resources/videos/cgi_neutral.mp4 (app.js:92053)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:92132)
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/sections/vision.vue?vue&type=template&id=0c8fcfd8&scoped=true (app.js:39037)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:92132)
    at Module../resources/vue/sections/vision.vue?vue&type=template&id=0c8fcfd8&scoped=true (app.js:87992)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:92132)
    at Module../resources/vue/sections/vision.vue (app.js:87291)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:92132)
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/index.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js (app.js:36141)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:92132)
./resources/videos/cgi_neutral.mp4 @ app.js:92053
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:92132
./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/sections/vision.vue?vue&type=template&id=0c8fcfd8&scoped=true @ app.js:39037
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:92132
./resources/vue/sections/vision.vue?vue&type=template&id=0c8fcfd8&scoped=true @ app.js:87992
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:92132
./resources/vue/sections/vision.vue @ app.js:87291
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:92132
./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/vue/index.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js @ app.js:36141
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:92132
./resources/vue/index.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js @ app.js:87384
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:92132
./resources/vue/index.vue @ app.js:86765
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:92132
./resources/js/router.js @ app.js:39210
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:92132
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:39103
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:92132
(anonymous) @ app.js:92297
__webpack_require__.O @ app.js:92169
(anonymous) @ app.js:92299
(anonymous) @ app.js:92301
```

[This git issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4603) says to install `scss-loader` but I already have it:

```
"sass-loader": "^12.2.0"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put file mp4 in public folder ? And it can be acccessed via browser with url like
`localhost:8000/videos/cgi_neutral.mp4` ,
then embed in component :

```
 <source
     size="1080"
     src="/videos/cgi_neutral.mp4"
     type="video/mp4"
 />
```

It is better than use loader with webpack + file-loader

Comment: Oh wow, that fixed it. Thank you stranger